# How do I include data-bs-toggle in my code

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use data-bs-toggle. I am very new in using bootstrap. I am not sure if I am forgetting to add a library.
When I start typing data-bs the only ones that my autocomplete show me is data-bs-target and data-bs-popper and if I add data-bs-toggle does not work it's like is not included in the package.

My code:
header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock%}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}{% endblock%}

</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% include 'header.html' %}

{% block title %} Home {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col md 12">
            <div class="jumbotron p-3">
                <h2>Manage <b>Student </b><button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" 
                data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#mymodal">Add new Student</button></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Image showing that data-bs-toggle is not showing:]

Comment: You can add it by typing it. It may not be shown in intellisense but it does not mean it is not included

Comment: ^ Yes, if you manually add it to the page once it will then appear in your auto-complete list?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score -1):

Not necessarily related to your auto-complete issues, but you have not properly included the Bootstrap libraries. Read through the [Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/) and specifically the [Starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template).

Your template should look something like the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock%}</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock%}

    <!-- bootstrap.js belongs down here ONCE, after ALL the content -->
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. In the video that I was watching the person said that bootstrap.min.css should be in the head but the rest did not matter if you put in the body or the head. But if it's more readable to add to the body I will start doing that.

Comment: It's not about readability, it's that BS js queries the document for `data-bs-*` elements to initialize the BS functionality, when it loads. If you load the BS js before the content the components  may not be properly initialized as they potentially get loaded into the document after the BS query. You could put it in the head but then you will most likely have to manually initialize all the components via custom js.